# How to overlay a fluid image with a same-size div element?

Tags: html, overlay, css

I have an image, which I would like :

- To cover maximum space of container, while fully visible and maintaining aspect ratio
- To be overlayed with same-size `div` element

Here is the HTML, pretty basic :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image"><!-- Image is the background of this div -->
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="dot"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS :

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: blue;
}
.image {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: yellow;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/70x40/000/fff.png)
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.dot {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 40%;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Image covering of the container is done using the `contain` CSS property of `background-size`.

**Problem is :** The overlay has the wrong dimensions (`.container` instead of `.image`), so the red dot does not stick to its position relatively to the image.

**Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/GTLMP/**

**Any idea how to achieve this without javascript ?**

One solution would be to add a wrapping `div` element with correct aspect ratio, then both `image` and `overlay` could be inner elements with absolute full width and height, however, I don't know how to do that in a way that this `div` would be fully fluid in the container `div`

**Other solution**, demoed in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/K4UR4/3/ , as suggested by MilanSxD, to use `inline-block` elements. It's partially working :

- In Chrome, even if initial state is Ok, vertically resizing breaks wrapper ratio
- In Firefox, max-height of image is not respected

Comment: The question is not very clear. Do you want the div to be the size of the image, or the image to be the szie of the div? Either way, using percentages won't work if you want to sync their sizes without Javascript. I take it you want to keep the Original proportions of the image?

Answer (score 0):

To the container, add:

display: inline-block;

Comment: By modifying a lot the example, it actually works _somewhat_ by mixing floats, clearfix, and inlin-block: http://fiddle.jshell.net/GTLMP/3/ But resizing the window gives sometimes good result, and sometimes unexpected (Chrome)

Comment: I'll try to find the answer to support Chrome tomorrow. I don't have any more time today.